# How to test canvas selenium c# project

Tags: c#, selenium

My Project has been using selenium to run it frontend regression tests for quite a while now. Due to a shift in Dev tools, an area of the screen that was using jquery to display some front-end stuff, has now shifted to using canvas element (HTML5?). This is causing me a bit of a headache as I have no idea how to go about testing something in selenium c# that has no tags, XPaths or identifiable factors with which to interact in the usual way.

The canvas effectively creates an entire hierarchy tree of different boxes, which depending on the text in the box, changes size and location(X and Y).

What is 'recommended' best way of interacting with a canvas element?

Comment: Does your canvas not have something on that you could locate?

Comment: The Canvas has a tag and then that is it - everything else is drawn within the canvas and that isn't visible when looking at the HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Talk to the dev team and have them write/expose the APIs that you need to do the desired testing. You can then call them using JS in your script.

My company converted a personalization page from Flash to HTML5 canvas a couple years ago and this is what I did and it's worked out fine. I generally use the UI like a user would to set up the scenario and then call the internal APIs to query the CANVAS on if an image was added, if the text displayed is correctly, etc.

Comment: Thank you for this JeffC, My Dev did suggest this method but I was unsure it would be effectively testing the front-end, as most of what the user can see is Canvas, there isn't really any other moving parts. I've actually gone a slightly different route using Sikuli Integrator. Very interesting and easy to get working (No API launchers like Sikuli4Net) - found more information here: https://qaagent.wordpress.com/2013/07/17/how-to-use-sikuli-in-my-c-coded-tests/ - But please, take my upvote kind internet stranger.